# encoding response in nodejs

Tags: node.js, html-encode

I have a server in nodejs. In some case, when I do request to some url, I get this response:

```
��i{�F�0���+0�{;Ҽ%9�;��+o��ډ�r&�����E1�P���~�V6$�����@��S�N��<��I:.V̊y���#�ϭ?=��p��֟�����X=~:�b�k�<K�˹J������!�ǖ�8�E�g��nϊb�?8<\�j�����a�������x>��n?~t�_���G����NZ�i8��w��d� (��
��|���ϟ}��g�:I�xUD���ѯj\|��W����엯���~3�����ç�~�������.��l/���������:��D]��B��?��    f
T*����J`>����A���y����כ�z��0.��kzZ��+K�s���ѻ�a�6����@����F���������V��q-*��ǻe����<�7�pW#�I4�x��r�_�j$��y�
v��q�ၤ�n��",
```

Here is a code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate, sdch");
    req.setEncoding('utf8');
    next();
});

app.post("/check", function(req, res) {
    var link = req.body.url;
    request(link, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body.toString('utf8'));
            res.json({ body: body.toString('utf8') });
        }
    });
});
```

How can I resolve this problem.

Comment: it's probably gzipped data, and it didn't get unzipped properly.

Comment: Yeah, maybe , but when I use  res.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate, sdch"); in PHP, I get encoding data. Now I would like to investigate it in nodejs

Comment: @VaheAkhsakhalyan. You can use `require('zlib').unzip(buffer, callback)` to decode Gzipped data.